# Creating a timer with ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

So I'm trying to figure out how to create a timer, I came across this:
[using ScheduledExecutorService to start and stop timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104088/using-scheduledexecutorservice-to-start-and-stop-timer)

The example they have seems to work pretty well. I'm just wondering if I'm utilizing this correctly:

```
  public class TimerTest 
{
  private ScheduledExecutorService  es = null;
  private  boolean timeIsUp = false;
  private ScheduledFuture futureHandler = null;
  private  TimeKeeper timeKeeper = null;
  private  String subject = "";
  private  int siteNo;
  private  long time; 
  private  boolean stop;




public  void endTimer()
{
    System.out.println("we should shutdown everything here");
    es.shutdownNow();
}

public  boolean stopTimer()
{

    if (timeKeeper != null)
    {
        timeKeeper.deactivate();
    }
    futureHandler.cancel(true);
 return true;

}
public  boolean isTimeup()
{
    return timeKeeper.isTimeUp();
}
public void startTimer(long mseconds, String subj, int sNo)
{
    subject = subj;
    siteNo = sNo;
    time = mseconds;
    timeKeeper = new TimeKeeper();
    callScheduler(mseconds);

}

public  boolean isTimerRunning()
{
    return (es.isShutdown() || es == null);

}
public void resetTimer(long t)
 {
    stopTimer();
    callScheduler(t);
 }

public  void resetTimer()
{

   resetTimer(time);  
}

private  void callScheduler(long mseconds)
{
    if (es == null)
        es = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
    timeKeeper = new TimeKeeper();
    futureHandler = es.schedule( timeKeeper, mseconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}


private class TimeKeeper implements Runnable  {
    //volatile for thread-safety

    private volatile boolean isActive = true;  
    private volatile boolean isTimeUp = false;
    public void run ()   {  
        if (isActive){
            callAlert();
            isTimeUp = true;
        }
    }  
    public void deactivate(){
        isActive = false;
    }

    public boolean isTimeUp()
    {
        return isTimeUp;
    }
    private void callAlert()
    {
        System.out.println("you are in the callAlert method");
    }
  }

 }
```

And here is the Test:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     long pastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     TimerTest timer = new TimerTest();
    timer.startTimer(15000, "bh", 1);
    long time;
    int count =0;
    boolean stop = false;
    while(true)
    {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - pastTime;

        if (time > 3000)
        {
            if (!stop){
                System.out.println("we are reseting the timer");
                timer.resetTimer(4000);

                timer.stopTimer();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3995);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            }
            stop = true;


        }
        if (timer.isTimeup())
        {
            System.out.println("our time is up");
            timer.endTimer();
            break;
        }
        if (!stop)
            System.out.println("hello");
        else
        {
            if (count == 0)
                System.out.println("we wait 10 seconds from now");
            count++;
        }


    }
    timer.resetTimer(1200);
    while (true)
    {
        if (timer.isTimeup())
        {
            timer.isTimeup();
            System.out.println("breaking after time is up");
            break;
        }
    }
    timer.endTimer();

}
```

This seems to work, I'm might of missed something that I need, this is my first time working with the ScheduledExecutorService Do you guys see any problems with this code? 
I don't want there to be conflict with thread collision.

Comment: Rather than asking people to go through your code, it'd be good if you can brief about what your code is doing and where do you face the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) you automatically get the timer feature. You don't need it explicitly unless you have something that the ScheduleExecutorService can't provide.
e.g. Let say you want to start a task after initial delay of 10 secs and then subsequent delays of 5 seconds each.

```
public void init() {
    executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize);
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new WorkerThread(), 10, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public void end() {
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: I need to make a timer that will reset the timer when it doesn't timeout (A certain task finishes before the timer times out). I know how to initiate a new scheduler, and how to end it. How would you reset it?, and how would you stop it? Maybe that should of been my question.
I don't think ending the scheduler completely is what I want.